# GoogleCustom API number of results

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

How is possible to get more results then 10 with googlecoustom API? I think its just take results from 1st page... when I type to search more then 10 I get this error:

Here is request:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Montenegro&cx=002715630024689775911%3Ajczmrpp_vpo&num=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
num=10 is number of results


400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid Value"
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid Value"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well It is not possible to get more than 10 result from Google Custom Search API.
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#query-params
As You can see for num parameter you valid values are only between 1 and 10 inclusive.

To get more result you should make multiple calls. in each different call, increase the value of parameter 'start' by 10. That should do it

Answer (score 1):

For first page result, use
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Montenegro&cx=002715630024689775911%3Ajczmrpp_vpo&num=10**&start=1**&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

This query asks google to provide 10 results starting from position 1. Now you can not ask google for more than 10 results at a time. So you have to query again asking for 10 result starting from 11. So In next query, keep **num=10** and **start=11**. Now you can get all the results by changing **start** value.