# How do I repeat a query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-custom-search

I need to repeat the following query in order to increase the results of google images. The code is executed after clicking on a button.

Google docs says:

> Google Custom Search and Google Site Search return up to 10 results
>   per query. If you want to display more than 10 results to the user,
>   you can issue multiple requests (using the start=0, start=11 ...
>   parameters) and display the results on a single page. In this case,
>   Google will consider each request as a separate query, and if you are
>   using Google Site Search, each query will count towards your limit.

[Other SO question says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427837/googlecustom-api-number-of-results#answer-17468889)

> To get more result you should make multiple calls. in each different
>   call, increase the value of parameter 'start' by 10.

And also [this one says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427837/googlecustom-api-number-of-results#answer-17589802):

> Now you can not ask google for more than 10 results at a time. So you
>   have to query again asking for 10 result starting from 11. So In next
>   query, keep num=10 and start=11. Now you can get all the results by
>   changing start value.

How can I repeat the following and increase the `start` parameter each time?

```
    function googleImages() {
        var myCx = "MY_CX";
        var myKey = "MY_KEY";
        $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", {
            q: termS + " in 1930 in " + country,
            alt: "json",
            searchType: "image",
            cx: myCx,
            num: 10,
            start: 0,
            key: myKey,
            rights: "cc_publicdomain",
            filter: "1",
            safe: "high",
            imgType: "photo",
            fileType: "jpg"
        },
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {    
                $(".my_images .row .grid").append('<div class="col-sm-4 grid-item"><div class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '"></div></div>');
            });
            var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
            // options
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            percentPosition: true
        });
        $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
            $grid.packery('layout');
        });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save `start` value between calls so as example you could use pattern like this:

```
   function createGoogleImagesLoader(initialValue) {
       var _start = initialValue || 0;
       var imagesCount = 10;

       return function() {
            $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", {
                ...
                num: imagesCount,
                start: _start
             },..);
            _start += imagesCount;

       }
    }

var googleImages = createGoogleImagesLoader();
googleImages() // load from 0 to 10
googleImages() // load from 10 to 20 etc.
```